# Error loading. Cannot open file

Tags: c#, model, 3d, xna, xbox

I'm new to XNA game development and I've faced a problem that couldn't solve even by searching on the internet. I wanted to load my model but every time it gives me this exception: ContentLoadException was unhandled. Here is my code:

```
 Model model = Content.Load<Model>(@"\Models\hero"); // and file is in fbx format
```

This is the screenshot of my solution
[image]

Comment: did you set the RootDirectory? `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";`

Comment: Can you show a picture of the Content folder structure?

Comment: @NahuelIanni see the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Model model = Content.Load<Model>(".\\Models\\hero");
```

What you're doing is perfectly fine. Just try doing it **Exactly** the way Microsoft suggests at the [MSDN Examples Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx). If it still doesn't work, you can know for sure there is something wrong on your part. Try placing the Model in the same directory so you can just:

```
Model model = Content.Load<Model>("hero");
```

And if that still doesn't work, you know the problem is somewhere else.